# Bind window closing event to an ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple WPF application where I don't have any mvvm framework like mvvmlight. Is there as way to bind a window close event to an ICommand that's in the view model?

I tried something like

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Close" Executed="{Binding WindowClose}" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

but obviously it doesn't work because it's looking for an event handler. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe on event Closing and invoke WindowClose.Execute(null) from code.
Or use EventToCommand (from some MVVM toolkits).

Comment: Ok, I can live with creating a simple event handler for `Closing`  event but how do I invoke the ICommand from that event handler. I can't use any MVVM toolkits at this moment.

Comment: WindowClose is an ICommand property in the view model. I don't think it's directly accessible like that in the event handler. I'll have to get at the view model from the datacontext and then call Invoke?

Comment: Yes, you can take this command from DataContext. How do you set DataContext for Window?

Comment: yes. It works but I don't like the type cast thought! Thanks for your help.